# What format is this PHP data in?

Tags: php, serialization

I'm trying to work out what format this data is in, so i can change it. It's just horrible.

```
a:20:{s:12:"tagline_text";s:0:"";s:8:"gAddress";s:40:"380 North Shore Drive, Pittsburgh, 15212";s:8:"latitude";s:9:"40.445917";s:9:"longitude";s:10:"-80.011324";s:5:"phone";s:0:"";s:5:"email";s:0:"";s:7:"website";s:44:"http://tequilacowboy.com/pittsburgh/wannabs/";s:7:"twitter";s:0:"";s:8:"facebook";s:0:"";s:8:"linkedin";s:0:"";s:11:"google_plus";s:0:"";s:7:"youtube";s:0:"";s:9:"instagram";s:0:"";s:5:"video";s:0:"";s:7:"gallery";N;s:12:"price_status";s:0:"";s:10:"list_price";s:0:"";s:13:"list_price_to";s:0:"";s:15:"claimed_section";s:0:"";s:4:"faqs";a:2:{s:3:"faq";a:1:{i:0;s:0:"";}s:6:"faqans";a:1:{i:0;s:0:"";}}}
```

Comment: I am curious why you want to change it. Its lovely structured data that a computer likes.

Comment: Where is the string coming from if you didn't serialize it? Changing it on a whim without knowing whats using it is not going to work. Some research in tracing where the string came from would lead you to [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function, hit the manual, you then have your answer.

Comment: I'm changing it for a client. The data isn't compatible with the new website.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the output of PHP serialize() to me. You may be able to decode it back into an array by writing a PHP script, read the data from its file or whatever, and use unserialize() on it.

I tested this guess:

```
<?php
// read $string from a file or something
print json_encode(unserialize($string));
```

Run this PHP code:

```
php myscript.php | jq .
```

Output:

```
{
  "tagline_text": "",
  "gAddress": "380 North Shore Drive, Pittsburgh, 15212",
  "latitude": "40.445917",
  "longitude": "-80.011324",
  "phone": "",
  "email": "",
  "website": "http://tequilacowboy.com/pittsburgh/wannabs/",
  "twitter": "",
  "facebook": "",
  "linkedin": "",
  "google_plus": "",
  "youtube": "",
  "instagram": "",
  "video": "",
  "gallery": null,
  "price_status": "",
  "list_price": "",
  "list_price_to": "",
  "claimed_section": "",
  "faqs": {
    "faq": [
      ""
    ],
    "faqans": [
      ""
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Always dangerous to help someone on a downvoted question!

Comment: @MortimerCat, I disagree. So many questions are downvoted for frivolous or subjective reasons that a downvote is not a reliable indicator of a bad question.

Comment: sorry, just letting off steam :)

Comment: Thanks so much for answering my question. I've been tearing my hair out.